# Fantasy Football Scorer Python

Tags: python, string

I need to create a program which reads a text file which contains a list of soccer players and have corresponding points to it. it asks for soccer players until there is no output and then it totals all the points.
Eg:

```
Player:Justin Westhoff
Player: Brodie Smith
Player: Brad Ebert
Player: 
Total score for team: 1401
```

I don't really have any idea how to do this. So far my code is:

```
z={}
b=input('Player: ')
c=0
while b != '':
   for player in open('players.txt'):
       print(player)
```

This only prints the list of the players. I am not sure how to get its scores added up. 
By the way, you can't hard-code it as there is over 200 players in the text file.

An example of the text file is:]

```
Brad Ebert,471
Brodie Smith,466
Kade Simpson,466
Luke Shuey,465
Justin Westhoff,464
Nic Naitanui,464
Chad Wingard,462
Jordan Lewis,459
Michael Johnson,459
Hamish Hartlett,458
Steven Motlop,457
Jaeger O'Meara,457
```

Comment: please, fix your code format.

Comment: Sorry, how do you that, i am new to this.

Comment: This is not a "we do your homework for you" website. Try to finish it on your own, and if you have a specific problem, articulate that.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really have any idea how to do this.

The main parts of your code are:

1. Read the point file, and associate each point with a player.
2. Keep a running total of the points for players entered.

For the the first part, you need to use a dictionary; which is Python's key/value store. Your keys are the player's names, and the value is the score.

In each line of your file, the player name and score is separated by a comma. So use `.split(',')` to split those apart.

You should read your file once, build the dictionary and then ask the user for input. You cannot ask for input, then open the file, search for the player, read the score and then calculate the value. This is not practical.

Finally, keep in mind that all data read from a file will be in strings, which means the score you read in this line `Brad Ebert,471` will be the string `'471'` and not the integer `471`. Use `int()` convert the score (otherwise, when you try to add the numbers, you'll get an error).

Good luck with your assignment!

Answer (score 0):

Your file is of such a format that you really only need to add up all the integers in the file. So you'll want to just extract the number on every line and add it to a running total. The following code will do that:

```
from re import findall
f = open(name-of-your-file-here, "r")
points = 0
textin = f.readlines()
for line in textin:
    points += int(('').join(findall(r'\d+', line)))
print points
f.close()
```

Here, `f.readlines()` reads all the lines of the file `f` into a list of strings. The regex using `findall` extracts integers from strings.

Comment: @DilshanWijesena I see that you've updated your question. I've updated my answer. I tested it on the input you provided, and it works.